# Envolvido x [Des]envolvido

Tags: significado, etimologia, origem-histórica, prefixos

Certo dia estávamos conversando sobre países *desenvolvidos*, e fiquei matutando sobre o significado de desenvolvido, e sua semelhança com a palavra *envolvido*, que estaria combinado com o prefixo *des-*.

A priori, devido aos significados comumente utilizados serem distintos, me pareceu que não havia relação nenhuma entre as duas palavras, porém, após uma reflexão mais calma, cheguei a conclusão de que podem realmente ter o mesmo radical.

O racional seria de que envolvido é algo amarrado, dependente "encasulado" - ao passo que desenvolvido seria algo evoluído, sem barreiras, ou obstáculos, independente.

Apesar de ter chegado a esta conclusão, gostaria de saber:

- Desenvolvido possui o mesmo radical que envolvido?
- Isso significa que, de certa forma, são antônimos?
- Existe algum uso histórico que explique a evolução do uso comum entre envolvido e desenvolvido?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, o radical é o mesmo, e já foram antónimos, mas entretanto a língua evoluiu. ***Envolver*** já vem do latim *involvo*, que significava “‘rolar sobre, enrolar, enroscar, esconder’” (Houaiss, Lisboa, 2003). ***Desenvolver*** formou-se já no português por *des* + *envolver* (Houaiss), e os primeiros significados com que aparece neste [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) é precisamente ‘desenrolar, desembrulhar’ e ‘desembaraçar’ (ênfase minha em todas as citações):

> E, tanto que o sol foy alto, mandaron os capitãães **desenvolver** suas bãdeiras e tanger as trombetas e vozinas pera todo homen se fazer prestes ao cõbato.
>   (Conde de Barcelos, *Crónica Geral de Espanha*, 1344.)
>
> […] e tirando dos peitos um lenço **desenvolveu** dele um anel
>   (João de Barros, *Crónica do imperador Clarimundo*, 1520.)
>
> Sempre o diabo a tais tempos traz embaraços de que me não pude **desenvolver** mais cedo
>   (Sá de Miranda, *Vilhalpandos*, 1533.)

Ainda em 1712 o [*Vocabulário Portuguez e Latino* de Rafael Bluteau](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ZMZKAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA137&dq=%22DESENVOLVER.%20Desfazer%20hum%20envolto%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6quuai83SAhXBbRQKHSlXBxgQ6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q=%22DESENVOLVER.%20Desfazer%20hum%20envolto%22&f=false) traz simplesmente:

> DESENVOLVER. Desfazer hum envolto [tradução em latim] ou *explicare* [tradução em latim]

Bem, por esta altura já tinha adquirido o significado de ‘explicar’, relacionado com o significado que hoje tem em *desenvolver um ideia, um argumento*. Mas entretanto *desenvolver* adquiriu mais uma porção de significados figurados, aproximando-se do verbo que nós conhecemos hoje, mas mantendo ainda a ligação a ‘desenrolar’. Vejamos o [*Diccionario da Lingua Portugueza* de Morais Silva de 1789:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KvFj2p9f8RgC&pg=PA410&dq=%22Ampliar%20,%20e%20explicar%20o%20que%20he%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwianpXBis3SAhUCWBQKHXh9AqYQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Ampliar%20%2C%20e%20explicar%20o%20que%20he%22&f=false)

> DESENVOLVER , v. at. Estender, desdobrar o que está envolto , encolhido. § f. Ampliar , e explicar o que he susceptivel de mais explicações , exposições. § Fazer crescer o feto , o embrião , o germe ; fazer abrir , desabotoar a flor do capulho , botão , &c. § Fazer que alguem perca o acanhamento , o pejo , o encolhimento , e timidez de quem não tem uso do mundo , ou não vio gente como se diz ; fazer perder o pejo , modéstia […] Desembaraçar , despejar : *v. g.* ,, *de negocios tão empeçados não se póde homem desenvolver limpamente ,, *Vilhalp. Acto* 3. *sc*. 7. §—*se de embaraços* ,, *Vilhalp.* 4 *sc.* 8.

Quase um século mais tarde, em 1873, no [*Thesouro da Lingua Portugueza* do Frei Domingos Vieira](https://books.google.pt/books?id=sWzh2uSTUQUC&pg=PA875&dq=%22Esta%20crean%C3%A7a%20desenvolveu-se%20com%20muita%20rapidez%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi34p33is3SAhUMcRQKHWn0DvwQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Esta%20crean%C3%A7a%20desenvolveu-se%20com%20muita%20rapidez%22&f=false), já se diz que o sentido “desdobrar, estender o que está envolto” é “pouco usado hoje”. Por outro lado já lá encontramos os sentidos de ‘desenvolvimento físico, intelectual e de tendências’. Exemplos do *Thesouro:*

> *Esta creança* desenvolveu-se *com muita rapidez*.
>
> *Com que rapidez um tal genio se* desenvolveu!
>
> *A mania de tomar banhos do mar* desenvolveu-se *ultimamente em Portugal*.

Apesar de não constar do *Thesouro*, já se econtram por esta altura as noções de [“desenvolvimento da indústria” (1865)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=4j9EAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA251&dq=%22t%C3%A3o%20contr%C3%A1ria%20ao%20desenvolvimento%20da%20ind%C3%BAstria%20e%20das%20artes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiswrbykdLSAhWEWhQKHXy3Dm8Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22t%C3%A3o%20contr%C3%A1ria%20ao%20desenvolvimento%20da%20ind%C3%BAstria%20e%20das%20artes%22&f=false) e [“desenvolvimento económico” (1882)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=OCtXAAAAMAAJ&q=%22desenvolvimento%20econ%C3%B3mico%22&dq=%22desenvolvimento%20econ%C3%B3mico%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKxof5j9LSAhWBlBQKHf42BCoQ6AEIiQIwJA). A primeira referência que encontrei a países, sem procurar muito aturadamente, foi [“desenvolvimento do Brasil” de 1929.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=RlkCAAAAMAAJ&q=%22desenvolvimento%20do%20Brasil%22&dq=%22desenvolvimento%20do%20Brasil%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcgLHlldLSAhXDthQKHUnMCpcQ6AEIITAB)

Estes novos sentidos de *desenvolver* poderão dever algo ao sentido mais antigo de ‘desembaraçar, libertar’. Creio que a via mais importante foi no entanto outra. *Desenvolver* significou ‘desenrolar, desdobrar, desembrulhar’; daí veio *desenvolver-se a flor* no sentido de ‘desabotoar a flor do capulho , botão’ (Moraes Silva, 1789); hoje diríamos que a flor abre ou desabrocha. Creio que terá vindo daqui a ideia de *desenvolver-se a criança, a indústria ou um país*; qualquer desta ideias pode hoje ser figuradamente descrita por *desabrochar* [(Michaelis 5)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?id=G38q).

Comment: Superou minhas expectativas - muito boa sua resposta, obrigado!